# Is there any to create Table of Contents using Python in MS Word

Tags: python, ms-word, word-automation

When we are doing it manually, we need to create some heading text and then under the reference tab, we can generate the table of content which is clickable. But I am not getting any idea of doing this in python.

[image]

Comment: which library do you use?. if none you can use **aspose-words** library to work with word files.

Comment: seems there is copyright text gets added every time you use that library.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Python. Word uses a TOC Field https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-toc-table-of-contents-field-1f538bc4-60e6-4854-9f64-67754d78d05c to generate automatic Tables of Contents. If you can insert the field with appropriate switches, you will get what you want.